# What are concerns with importing { history } object directly into modules and using it there?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history, react-router-v4

I did stumble over a problem where I couldn't get access to a synced history object. I think it is good practice to use withRouter then. However, when using the history object provided by withRouter and pushing on it the pushed state would not be reflected in the location object provided by withRouter. Strangely enough it would be reflected in the history object originally provided to my Router.

I came up with a bit of strange solution (I think). I just import the history object into the component module where I want to use it and use it there as a local variable. It does feel hacky to import the history into my modul, and thus bypassing react tree, redux store and react router altogether.
However, it is working and not causing any bugs so far. Is there a problem that I am unaware of?

See code below.

I instantiate my history object in: 
 **store.js module**:

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
...
const history = createHistory();
...
export { history , store }
```

that as you can see exports history. I then feed said history to my Router (ConnectedRouter in my case, as I am using react-router-redux) in: 
**routes.js module**

```
import { store , history } from '/imports/client/store';

const MyStoreRouter = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={ history }>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing}/>
                        <Route path="/" component={MainApp}/>
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </ConnectedRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
};
```

Now for the wacky part. I import the history into a display component: 
**DisplayComponent.js module:**

```
import { history } from '/imports/client/store';
....
export default class EventCreationModal extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            selectedCategory: (history.location.state && history.location.state.category) ? history.location.state.category : 'sports',
        };
        history.listen((location,action) => {
            this.setState({
                selectedCategory: (history.location.state && history.location.state.category) ? history.location.state.category : 'sports',
            })
        }); 
    }

    handleSelect(key) {
        history.push("/Home",{'category':key})
    }

render () {
    return (
        <Tabs activeKey={this.state.selectedCategory} onSelect={this.handleSelect} id="SportOrSocialSelector">
            <Tab eventKey={'sports} .../>
            <Tab eventKey={'social} .../>
        </Tabs>
    )
}
```